# how to build a tree structure in C++ using std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, tree

I am trying to write a tree sort of structure in C++. As in every tree there are branches and leaves. A branch can contain other branches as well as leaves. 
Now my implementation calls for each branch and leaf to have different functionalities. So for example.
Take the tree structure

```
                                          Root                                             
                                |                          |                             
                             Branch1                     Branch2                     Branch3
      |                |                |
    Leaf1            Leaf2           Branch4
```

> Now Each Leaf and branch has a different function to execute so Leaf1 will have a function called leaf1_func, Leaf2 will have leaf2_func, Branch4 has Branch4_func.

I was initially trying to implement composite design pattern. But that means I would have as many classes as leafs. But since I have tons of leaves and branches I would like to avoid creates more classes. I realize this is an unusual situation but was hoping somebody could help me in this regard. What would be the best way to implement this tree without creating too many classes.

i am using map STL container to store datas as well, i want to use this tree implementation to solve this in TSP problem.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int n=4;
int min=1, max=10;




struct graph
{
int nodes;//total no. of nodes or vertices namely cities
std::map<std::pair<int,int>, int> graphMap;//an object that links a pair of vertices   
};


void directed_Graph(graph);

void directed_Graph(graph G)
{
//int n = G->nodes; //city count
int i, j;
for(i = 0; i <= n-1; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j <= n-1; j++)
    {
        if(i!=j)
        {
            G.graphMap[std::make_pair(i,j)] = (rand()%10)+1;
            //cout<<G.graphMap[std::make_pair(i,j)]<<"\n";
        }

        else
        {
            G.graphMap[std::make_pair(i,j)] = 0;
        }

    }
}
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
graph g;
g.nodes = 4;

directed_Graph(g);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's up with the quoted text block? Is this homework?

Comment: @Potatoswatter, no its not homework, i wanna suggestion how to avoid using those functions

Answer (score 1):

Different functions with the same signature do still have the same type. Even if the functions are completely unrelated, you can have a tree that stores random data by using `void *` (type erasure) and then typecast back to the known actual type after the leaf node is reached.

```
struct node {
    void (*fptr)(); // pointer to any function taking no args, no return
    void *data; // pointer to anything, need to cast before using
};

void f() { std::cout << "hello"; }
void g() { std::cout << "world"; }

node a = { f, f };
node b = { g, g };

a.fptr();
static_cast< void (*)() >( b.data )();
```

You could also use virtual methods with inheritance and store pointers to base class type in the tree. It depends on what the nodes really are.

None of this is really related to the fact it goes into a graph.

Comment: it was ok, can you help me regarding dynamic way of tree implementation and paralleling it.

Comment: @visanio_learner Well, if you've already chosen a viable tree implementation, there's no sense in changing it unless you have a good reason. What you show above is fine, except the vertices are `int` so there's no function involved. Edit: Oh, but you should call graphMap.size() instead of having a variable `int nodes;`.

Comment: there's no func involved in my code, i know that, i wanna get ideas from experts, that how do i use to implement a tree structure for that graph that i created using map(stl container) i hope u might have understood my problem now... you also suggested me that maultimap is good, i agree with that.

Comment: @visanio_learner There are plenty of ways to implement a tree, each suited to different algorithms and applications. You have chosen one good way, but there's no way to say which is best without what you're doing. It seems you've solved the graph problem, and you need an answer to the functions problem, which is separate. Either way, I need more specifics to give a better answer.

Comment: i need to build a tree for this graph that i created for now, is ternary tree struct is good for me, since i have lots of children for root node itself, if my n-value is 5 city problem, then i might have 4 children... what should i use? is ternary tree is good enough to solve my problem

Comment: @visanio_learner If the tree is going to be a subset of the directed graph, then I would say to use the same format for both of them: `std::map< std::pair< int, int >, node >`. Note that for a city of with id N, you can get all its outgoing edges by iterating from `graphMap.lower_bound( make_pair( N, 0 ) )` to `graphMap.lower_bound( make_pair( N+1, 0 ) )`. So that should help make the graph look more like a tree.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of you diagram it seems that you want a tree where the nodes can have more than two children.  If that's the case then the STL containers are not going to work for you.  They are are self balancing binary trees.

If you're OK with a binary tree then there are a couple ways to do this.  The first is to write functions and then to store function pointers or functors in the tree.

```
#include <set>

int foo( ) {
  return 5;
}

std::set< int (*)( ) > my_set;
my_set.insert( &foo );
```

The problem with this approach is that all of your functions have to have the same type, i.e. take the same arguments and have the same return type.  What's more, while they can define different behaviors, they cannot keep state, i.e. you cannot store data in a function pointer.

The second options, as you mentioned, is to write classes.  If you need to vary the behavior of the nodes then the best way to do that is to define an interface and use polymorphism.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

struct base {
  virtual void print( ) const = 0;
};

struct derived1 : public base {
  void print( ) const { std::cout << "derived1" << std::endl; }
};

struct derived2 : public base {
  void print( ) const { std::cout << "derived2" << std::endl; }
};

std::set< base* > my_set;

my_set.insert( new derived1( ));
my_set.insert( new derived2( ));
```

You did not say whether you need to force certain behaviors to be leaves and other to be internal nodes, or if the nodes need to be ordered in a particular way, but if you do then you may be able to accomplish this by creating a custom less-than function:

```
bool operator < ( base const * const b1, base const * const b2 ) {
  // Figure out which is less here.
}
```

Again, if you need something that isn't a binary tree, though, then you're out of luck.  And any way you slice this you will need to write some code implementing the behavior stored in each node, whether it's functions or classes.

Comment: I don't see how this results in a tree structure.

Comment: I don't think OP is even aware that STL uses trees "under the hood." To him it's an irrelevant implementation detail.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, look i have edited my query, look my coding so far i have done using #include<map>, i don't need 'set' stl container, i see map is one way to store data efficiently.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: In many senses, it *is* an implementation detail.  `std::set` and `std::map` don't expose a parent-child relationship to the user, so they're not useful if you want an actual tree that you can manipulate in a tree-like fashion.

Comment: @Oli: Yeah, that's fair.  I suppose I was a bit too focused on the idea of ordered storage and not enough on the tree structure itself, which, as you point, seems to be the main issue here.

Answer (score 0):

if you have limited depth of tree  it's convenient to describe it like this:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, double> action_map_t;
typedef std::map<std::string, action_map_t> objid_map_t;
typedef std::map<std::string, objid_map_t> objtype_map_t;
```

//....etc here is depth == 3

```
objtype_map_t m_mapTooltipDuration;
m_mapTooltipDuration[objtype][objid][action] = atof(duration.c_str());
```